# Lebesgue integral vs. Riemann integral

Tags: lebesgue-integral

In Riemann integral, we define $$\int_a^b f:=\sup\left\{\int_a^b \varphi \mid \varphi \leq f \text{ where }\varphi \text{ step function}\right\}=\inf\left\{\int_a^b \varphi \mid f\leq \varphi \text{ where $\varphi $ step function}\right\},$$

whereas in Lebesgue integral, we define (if $f\geq 0$)

$$\int_a^b f:=\sup\left\{\int_a^b \varphi \mid 0\leq \varphi \leq f \text{ where }\varphi \text{ simple function}\right\}.$$

---

Except the fact that in Lebesgue, this definition is restricted to non-negative function, why in Lebesgue integral
$$\sup\left\{\int_a^b \varphi \mid 0\leq \varphi \leq f \text{ where }\varphi \text{ simple function}\right\}=\inf\left\{\int_a^b \varphi \mid   f\leq \varphi  \text{ where }\varphi \text{ simple function}\right\},$$
is not required?

Comment: the infimum will not work to define an integral of Lebesgue because a simple function is bounded by definition, however $f$ doesn't need to be bounded to be Lebesgue integrable. However in the integral of Riemann $f$ need to be bounded to be Riemann integrable, so we can use the infimum to define it integral.

Comment: @Masacroso: Thank you. So, if $f$ is bounded (in Lebesgue case), will the infimum and supremum coincident or still won't ?

Comment: it will coincide as far $f$ will be a Lebesgue measurable function